# How could I clean the CacheStorage in AppData\Roaming\Code\Service Worker?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I would like to know how the files in AppData\Roaming\Code\Service Worker\CacheStorage are generated? And can I clean them up? Because they occupy 13G+ space in C:/.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's this issue https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/130494

It's **safe**, people deleted it manually without facing any problem.

Cause:

It seems like the **\ServiceWorker** folder can be built up by some extensions.

In my case, I inspected a sample file

\Service Worker\CacheStorage\768996009f5f7cefe57f5576ea81651bad2f6abc\f4c82438-9918-4d65-975e-5b85cf33c2f7\e23fca550ee125f5_0

and found some text related to an extension **cweijan.vscode-database-client2-4.1.1**, which happens to be the one I ve been using quite extensively.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 0):

When the vscode extension creates a webview, vscode will create a cache file in this directory, you can delete it.